# Javascript enter key opening page in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, function, onsubmit, onkeypress

I am working with a search box and I have tried multiple fixes all of which reflect in the code. When you click the search button the search bar works and takes you to the search page however if you press the enter key it just pulls a refreshed version of the current page into a new tab. Does anybody know a way to fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
</head>
<body></body>
<div class="body"></div>
        <div class="grad"></div>
        <div class="header">
            <div>Abuse<span>Caboose</span></div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="login.html">Login</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="Media_Page.html">Media</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="Bios.html">Our Team List </a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us! </a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/lmn/image/upload/e_sharpen:150,f_auto,fl_lossy,q_80/v1/gameskinny/5edfe8862832766bd1c9a38e6a9821eb.jpg" alt="I am Support" title="Image" width="400" height="200" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="tfheader">
        <form target="_blank">
                <div><input type="text" placeholder="Search Google" onchange="urlinput(event)" onkeypress="return searchit()"></div>
                <br />
    <a id="searchbutton" href="" onclick="searchit()" target="_blank" onkeypress="return searchit()">Search</a>
    </form>
    </div>
<script>
const baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=";
var userurl;
var enterurl;
function urlinput(event){
var text = event.target.value;
text = text.replace(" ", "+");
userurl = text;
var searchButton = document.getElementById('searchbutton').href="baseUrl";
}
  function searchit()
  {
    document.getElementById("searchbutton").href= baseUrl + userurl; 
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textbox is inside a form and is submitting the form by default when you hit enter. Override the form's default submit behavior by handling the `onsubmit` function. If you return false from this function, the form will not submit.

```
<form target="_blank" onsubmit='return handleSubmit();'>
    <div><input type="text" placeholder="Search Google" onchange="urlinput(event)" onkeypress="return searchit()"></div>
    <br />
    <a id="searchbutton" href="" onclick="searchit()" target="_blank" onkeypress="return searchit()">Search</a>
</form>


<script>
  function handleSubmit() {
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: i have tried to use event.preventDefault(); it still behaved the same. I have also tried event.stopPropagation();

Comment: Your case is a little different than I thought. Override the onsubmit function of the form. See my updated answer.

Comment: I tried to implement your fix however it is still activating the same as it was. It seems as though its not even using the onsubmit command

Comment: nevermind your fix worked I forgot the () brackets at the end of the function name. however now it completely cancels out the form submission even through use of the button.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple fix. Just remove the form tag, you don't need it as you have java script to handle search. This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
    </head>
    <body></body>
    <div class="body"></div>
            <div class="grad"></div>
            <div class="header">
                <div>Abuse<span>Caboose</span></div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="login.html">Login</a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="Media_Page.html">Media</a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="Bios.html">Our Team List </a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us! </a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/lmn/image/upload/e_sharpen:150,f_auto,fl_lossy,q_80/v1/gameskinny/5edfe8862832766bd1c9a38e6a9821eb.jpg" alt="I am Support" title="Image" width="400" height="200" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="tfheader">
            <form>
                    <div><input type="text" placeholder="Search Google" onchange="urlinput(event)" onkeydown="newSearchit();"></div>
                    <br />
        <a id="searchbutton" href="" onclick="searchit()" onkeypress="return searchit()">Search</a>
        </form>
        </div>
    <script>
    const baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=";
    var userurl;
    var enterurl;
    function urlinput(event){
    var text = event.target.value;
    text = text.replace(" ", "+");
    userurl = text;
    var searchButton = document.getElementById('searchbutton').href="baseUrl";
    }
      function searchit()
      { 
        //alert('Inhere');
        document.getElementById("searchbutton").href= baseUrl + userurl; 
      }

        function newSearchit()
      { 
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById("searchbutton").click();
        }
      }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Try this out!!!